# can't scrape twitter with scrapy: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: python, twitter, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a twitter account to know the number of followers and the friends accounts. The scraping is done with Scrapy.

I started with requesting to login to twitter but failed with the following log message:

> 404 https://twitter.com/sessions/change_locale>: HTTP status code is
>   not handled or not allowed

the spider I am running with Scrapy is:

```
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

class CrawlSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'twitter_friends'
    allowed_domains = ['twitter.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.twitter.com/login'
    start_urls = ['https://twitter.com/account/following',
               'https://twitter.com/account/following']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/+'),
             callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

def init_request(self):
    print "called init request..."
    return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

def login(self, response):
    print "called login ..."
    twitter_response = FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'myUserName', 'password': 'myPassword'},
                callback=self.check_login_response)
    return twitter_response

def check_login_response(self, response):
    if "Hi sara" in response.body:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        # Now the crawling can begin..
        self.initialized()
    else:
        self.log("Bad times :(")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.

def parse_item(self, response):
    # here I parse the urls
```

Any help?

Comment: There could be a bunch of reasons, the most common one is either your `user_agent` string getting denied or it has something to do with headers. Try replicating the headers you'd see when loging in. You can check that by opening network inspector dev tools of your browser and inspecting the post request being made when you click the log in button.

Comment: Why not use the Twitter API?

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker